# ¿Cómo vincular un JPanel a una tecla "Enter"?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-11

> He creado el siguiente label (con funcionalidad de botón):

```
JLabel btAcept = new JLabel(scaledPrimaryAceptButton);
```

> Este label pretende checkear en un BBDD si existe un usuario introducido por teclado (login).
> He utilizado esté método para el checkeo:

```
private void checkUserExists() {
    Database database = new Database(txtUser.getText(), String.valueOf(passUser.getPassword()));
    StudentWindow student = new StudentWindow();

    if (!txtUser.getText().isBlank() && !String.valueOf(passUser.getPassword()).isBlank()) {
        // Checkea si existe usuario y se loguea
        if (database.isUser()) {
            // Cierra la ventana y se loguea como usuario
            if (database.getUserType().equals("alumno")) {
                student.openWindow();
                dispose();
            }
        } else lblErrorMessage.setText("¡Error en el usuario o contraseña!");
        
    }
    else lblErrorMessage.setText("¡Error al dejar campos vacíos!");
}
```

> Y mi problema es que quiero dar esta funcionalidad mediante la tecla "Enter". He implementado los métodos del objeto KeyListener, pero no consigo que me funcione correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Al final conseguí solucionarlo tomando cómo ejemplo el siguiente enlace al vídeo https://youtu.be/2_AteD52jCg

Comment: La mejor forma de explicar esto es con un breve ejemplo de cómo dejaste el código